# What do you do when you need high performance shared state in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Erlang is great about cleaning things up by not having shared state. But what happens when you do want shared state? For example: configuration options, statistics gathering, event/callback servers. Spawning up a new processes with some record as state or using the process dictionary is a way to accomplish shared state. You would loop that process over and over and reply to any messages. Multiple processes will just query that process using what are essentially impure getter and setter functions that wrap around message passing, but here we just turned Erlang into an impure object that's slower than a java object because of the reduction system taking turns is slower than just having a memory mutex around each global state. It even has the possibility of having a mailbox overflow if we're not careful.

So what do you do if you want fast shared state? Reddis, a database, mnesia, spawns looping state? How do you make centralized state more purely functional in erlang?

Comment: I'm sorry--why did you tag this question with "elixir"?

Comment: Because it's the same VM

Comment: How does that affect your question?  Would it be appropriate to add a joxa tag?  How about lisp-flavored Erlang?  If your question is about Erlang that's the only tag that should be on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a public (anyone can read or write) or protected (one writer, multiple readers) [ets table](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) created with the `named_table` option. Each process needing access to the shared state in the table can get to the table by its name.

Comment: If you are using ETS in a large system it can also be interesting to test and benchmark with the `write_concurrency` and/or `read_concurrency` options enabled, depending on the use case.

Comment: Do you think this is preferable to a gen_server using the process dictionary as state? I know ETS has some C code behind it and isn't like mnesia which is pure Erlang.

Comment: @BreezyChick89, the issue with a `gen_server` using the process dictionary for state is that any process wanting access to the state has to call into the `gen_server` process to get it, and that `gen_server` can become a bottleneck. I wrote [an article about process bottlenecks](http://steve.vinoski.net/blog/2011/03/19/process-bottlenecks-in-erlang-web-apps/) in 2011 that explores similar issues.

Comment: One benefit of using a `gen_server` is that it can provide a transaction type interface to the data which is practically impossible using ETS. You could go sort of half-way by having the tables readable by all but only writeable by one process, but it would only support simple, sort-of transactions.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their insight! Awesome to have so many experts comment!